# Can't flash stock recovery Nexus 7 2013

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-7, fastboot

I have a Nexus 7 2013 LTE device and I want to go back from TWRP to stock recovery. I've downloaded the factory-image lmy47o and extracted recovery.img and boot.img but I can't flash them:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
sending 'recovery' (7806 KB)...
OKAY [  0.250s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: image is not a boot image)
finished. total time: 0.253s
```

I get the same error with boot.img. What am I doing wrong?
(I can flash any other recovery or kernel, just the stock ones doesn't work)